# How do I renconcile electric potential and field of a dipole along its perpendicular bisector?

Tags: electric-fields, potential, dipole

It's been a while since I've studied electrostatics and is my first time posting here, so please forgive me if I'm missing something basic.

According to my reference book, the electric potential of a dipole along its perpendicular bisector is zero. Assuming a point P near a dipole such that the distance between the point P and the two end-point charges $q$ and $-q$ is constant, implying that the angle between the line of distance $r$ joining P and the midpoint of $q$ and $-q$ is $\theta=90^\circ$. Now varying this distance $r$ while keeping the angle constant, the potential energy remains zero and no work is done while traveling along the perpendicular bisector.

And we know that the electric field is non-zero along the perpendicular bisector and will definitely vary when r varies. How does this make sense when potential difference between two points divided by the displacement between them is supposed to give the negative of the electric field component in that direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please regard this answer as complementary to Farcher's.

The potential of a point P may be defined as the work needed per unit 'test' charge to bring a test charge to P from infinitely far away.

Suppose we choose to bring the test charge to P by taking it towards the dipole along the perpendicular bisector of the dipole. No work is done on the test charge ($q$) because we are not pushing it against any opposing force: the electric force $q\vec E$ is at right angles to each increment of displacement, because along the perpendicular bisector the electric field is always parallel to the axis of the dipole.

Work done over displacement $d\vec s$ is $dW=q\vec E.d\vec s=0$.

The same result (zero potential at P) is obtained whichever route we take the test charge from infinity to P.

Comment: "The electric force $q\vec E$ is at right angles to each increment of displacement, because along the perpendicular bisector the electric field is always parallel to the axis of the dipole."
That's what I have been missing, it makes perfect sense now. Thank you for clarifying!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an equipotential potential diagram produced by [Wolfram Electric Dipole Potential](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ElectricDipolePotential/).

[image]

As you will see there is a equipotential line between the two charges.

Perpendicular to that equipotential line line you will note that the potential changes from high on the right to low on the left chowing that the potential gradient is negative to the left, ie the direction of the electric field.
This continues all along that central equipotential line.

Answer (score 0):

> How does this make sense when potential difference between two points divided by the displacement between them is supposed to give the negative of the electric field component in that direction?

I think the use of "potential difference between two points" in this sentence invites a misconception.

Using @Farcher's diagram, let's call the $0$-volt-equipotential line $x=0$
and the locations $(-1,0)$ for $-Q$ and $(1,0)$ for $+Q$.

- The diagram is a plot of the "potential due to the two charges".
- The $0$-volt-equipotential line $x=0$ is geometrically-between the two charges.
- The electric field is the minus-the-gradient of the "potential due to the two charges", which is calculated for each point P using the potential at the points-near-P (*not just the potential at point-P*).
  With these points-near-P, we compute the potential difference between them, divided by their displacement (in the limit as these points approach point P).

Using @Farcher's link to [Wolfram Electric Dipole Potential](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ElectricDipolePotential/),
one can select "Contour Plot" and then activate the check box "show field direction".

If the potential graph were a surface to walk on,
we would find that the ground is not level when walking along the 0-volt-equipotential line.

[image: contour plot]